# How to fetch BLOB data in same format

Tags: php, pdf, blob, tcpdf

I am new in PHP. I have a web form which have textarea having data type BLOB. I am trying to fetch my data on pdf using TCPDF. I face problem while fetching Text area Data. When I fetched it, It Lose its Formatting. I store my Data in multiple paragraph but it show my data in single para graph. Line spacing converting into  **/r/r/r/n** and where i use apostrophe it also converted into **///'**. For example when i write PSO's it display as PSO///'s.
To store BLOB data i use

`$text = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['text'] );`
can anyone suggest me how to retrieve my BLOB data in same format?

Comment: @Dagon My Question is totally Different from You mentioned question.

Comment: no its not `nl2br` is the answer

Comment: @Dagon nl2br is not its answer. i am not using nl2br. I simple use textarea to store my text